# Is there a way to calculate a rolling average in pandas and exclude the max/min values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, moving-average, rolling-computation

In python, I'm trying to calculate the "Average of 5" or "Average of 12" statistic used when solving Rubik's cubes.

For the Average of 5 or Ao5, the quickest and slowest time is removed from the most recent 5 solving times and the average of the 3 remaining solving times is calculated.

E.g. If my last 5 times were 30, 10, 20, 40, 80 - the 10 and 80 would be excluded and the average would be calculated from the 3 remaining times of 30, 20 and 40 giving an Ao5 of 30.

Is there a way to do this in pandas and exclude the largest and smallest numbers (or outliers)? I've tried multiple ways without success. The rolling average would be perfect if it could exclude outliers.

Some sample data to work with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': {0: 232.74, 1: 157.80, 2: 215.55, 3: 86.91, 4: 187.15, 5: 192.56},
                   'turns': {0: 212, 1: 168, 2: 94, 3: 127, 4: 125, 5: 160}})
df
```

I'm trying to create an Ao5 column that stores this statistic.

In the Ao5 column in the last row i'd expect to see the average of the last 5 numbers excluding the largest and smallest numbers, so the average of 157.80, 187.15, 192.56 (as 215.55 and 86.91 are excluded).

In the Ao5 column in the second last row i'd expect to see the average of the last 5 numbers excluding the largest and smallest numbers, so the average of 157.80, 215.55, 187.15 (as 232.74 and 86.91 are excluded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
def mean_clipped(data):
    to_calc = data.sort_values()[1:-1]
    return np.mean(to_calc)

df.rolling(5).apply(mean_clipped)
```

It uses a rolling window and then applies a custom aggregate function. In this case it sorts the values from the window and then removes the first and last, then finds the mean.

Output:

```
         time       turns
0         NaN         NaN
1         NaN         NaN
2         NaN         NaN
3         NaN         NaN
4  186.833333  140.000000
5  179.170000  137.333333
```

Comment: If it was useful please upvote the answer and accept it. Thanks!